# Python-Vlc code to play next audio track in a Dual Audio Video and a python vlc code to disable or load external subtitles

Tags: python-3.x, python-vlc

am using tkinter and python vlc module to stream and display videos but the issue is, when i play a movie on a specific website using my code, the video has dual audio and the bad thing the english language is the second one. and it comes with the first one, spanish language, and another is the movie comes with subtitles but i have tried everything but the subtitles ain't removed. Does anybody know the solution. Am very thankful for ur help in Advance

when trying to add a blank srt file to disable the other subtitles, i used
`Sub = player.add_slave(player,"blank.srt", True)`
but ran into an error;
  `File "d:\Cautions\desktop cred\workspace\vlc.py", line 3893, in add_slave return libvlc_media_player_add_slave(self, i_type, str_to_bytes(psz_uri), b_select) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "d:\Cautions\desktop cred\workspace\vlc.py", line 6869, in libvlc_media_player_add_slave return f(p_mi, i_type, psz_uri, b_select) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
`ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: TypeError: wrong type`

also the audio i tried ;
`value = media_player.audio_set_track(2)`
but failed again